# Odoo/PHP: how can I set "order by" in API call?

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-9

Using the [ripcord](https://github.com/poef/ripcord) XML-RPC client and making a call like the following, how can I tell it by which field(s) to sort the records?

```php
$models = ripcord::client($cfg['url'] . '/xmlrpc/2/object');
$srch = $models->execute_kw($cfg['db'], $cfg['uid'], $cfg['pw'], 'account.move.line', 'search_read', array(array(array('account_id', '=', 174), array('date', '>=', '2016-01-01'))));
```

Using Odoo 9 Community Edition.

Comment: AFAIK there's no `order by` for that. However, you could use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)/[uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [signature of `search_read`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d4d5181285196f6c3e311a6afdd356f4dc2851ef/openerp/models.py#L5274) is:

```py
def search_read(self, cr, uid, domain=None, fields=None, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None):
```

I am not very familiar with PHP, but something like this should work:

```php
$models = ripcord::client($cfg['url'] . '/xmlrpc/2/object');
$srch = $models->execute_kw(
    $cfg['db'],
    $cfg['uid'],
    $cfg['pw'],
    'account.move.line',
    'search_read',
    array(
        array(
            array('account_id', '=', 174),
            array('date', '>=', '2016-01-01')
        ),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'date desc, id',
    )
);
```

We pass `NULL` for `fields`, `offset` and `limit` to use the default value and `order` is a comma-separated list of fields to sort on. In the above example it will return the move lines sorted by `date` in descending order and then by `id` (if some move lines have the same date) in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving here from search engines, the same syntax in python will look like:

```
pickings = models.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'search_read',
                          [[['state', '=', 'done'], ['date_done', '>', '2019-01-01']]],
                          {'fields':['name'], 'offset': 0, 'limit': 5, 'order': 'date_done desc'})
```